# Yii2 query mysql, Adding A Column that doesn't exist in a query

Tags: mysql, yii2

I woud like get a column that doesn't exist but return error

Normal way is:

```
SELECT 1 AS flag....
```

in yii:

```
Model::find()->select("1 AS flag, ...)...
```

the problem is that the query return with apexes

```
SELECT `1` AS `flag`
```

I already tryed with array but is the same result.

how can I do?

Thanks,
Gabriele.

Answer (score 2):

The function `findBySql` might work for you:

```
$sql = 'SELECT 1 as flag ...';
$model = Model::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

Comment: `<snide>`Sometimes 3rd party software gets in the way of using the underlying database`</snide>`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from **gmc** answer, you can also declare the variable in your model class and then use it in query as alias.

```
class YourModelName extends ActiveRecord
{
     public $flag;
}
```

Then your below query will work.

```
Model::find()->select("1 AS flag, ...)...
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: thank you, I will try to solution too next time... if is working is not bad

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this after spotting this nugget of detail in the Yii docs:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#select()-detail

> The method will automatically quote the column names unless a column
> contains some parenthesis (which means the column contains a DB
> expression)

So... if you're selecting a fixed string you could wrap the selected "column" in a string function such as `LTRIM()`, which won't do anything except fool Yii into not quoting the string with backticks.

```
Model::find()->select("LTRIM(1) AS flag, ...)...
```

You also need to add `flag` as a property of the model as previously suggested - then you can use the output of the query as `$Model->flag`